# UPDATE in procedure ORA-00001

Tags: oracle, plsql, indexing, sql-update

I have w problem with UPDATE in procedure. Procedure compiling and I see(DBMS...) results example 100records and error
`ORA-00001: unique constraint violated (CUSTOMER_INFO_COMM_METHOD_UX)`

My update:

```
UPDATE customer_info_comm_method_tab SET Value=wynikOK WHERE 
         customer_id=cus_rec.customer_id AND method_id='E_MAIL' AND Value = p_stringWyn;
```

1. wynikOK - actual new Value
2. cus_rec.customer_id - actual customer_id from cursor
3. p_stringWyn - old Value in table

key is founded on three attributes that I use (CUSTOMER_ID, VALUE, METHOD_ID)

Of course I can't remove index CUSTOMER_INFO_COMM_METHOD_UX because Its not my database

If I commented update procedure compile 100% without error but I need to do this update

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You're violating a unique key constraint. The only way to remove this error is to not violate that constraint.

Comment: "If I commented update procedure compile 100% without error" --- so comment it!

Comment: ZERKMS: But I must do this Update

Comment: @Przemek: you cannot perform an update that violates constraint. Constraints are added so you don't break integrity, but you wish to do so. So either change your mind or remove the constraint.

Comment: Then either your unique constrain (primary key) is inappropriate and you should pick another primary key or you need to rethink the requirement to update to that value and answer the problem a different way.

Comment: OK now its OK. I write code which check then this record exists or no If not exists I make Update

Thanks for help everyone !

Answer (score 0):

It means that your new value (wynikOK) is causing the violation. The combination of customer_id , your new value(wynikOK) and method id is already existing in another row of your table. But this has to be unique...

If this combination of values(customer,value,method) is not gonna be unique , then remove the unique constraint in the table..

Else value has to be unique. Try appending some strings for your new value so that it will be unique. Say if your value is 1234, try appending the date to this value 1234_23112012 so that this will be unique always.